# Past deleted order details being used by new orders

Tags: orders

So in the past we made the mistake of deleting orders from our Magento store.

We had an order today where a UK customer purchased a book.  They paid and received all the correct notification via email.

We then logged in to the admin to review the order.  It was completely different from the email notification.  It had a US address, a different payment method, products were added which no longer exist.  These details were from past test orders.

Another thing we noticed is that the confirmation email was also sent to other users, not in any way connected with this order.

I know we made a mistake in deleting past orders and that is undoubtedly the cause of our problem, but does anybody have any advice on how to reset things, without starting afresh.

Answer (score 1):

If you have remember your last order # then, You can change increment id of order to solve this problem.
Suppose your last test order # was 100000367 then change it by 100000500
To do this you need to do it by phpmyadmin look for this table

> eav_entity_store

And change the value of increment_last_id field where entity_type_id = 5 
Please check it on demo to avoide any problem.

Comment: I have two 'entity_type_id = 5' rows.  Is that right?

Comment: I have not sure it's right or not but change the both row value, if there increment_last_id is same

Comment: In my db there is only 1 row with 'entity_type_id = 5,

Comment: OK, so I changed the increment order, made a test purchase and although the order appears OK in the admin area, the email notifcation was sent out to myself (as the customer), but also a past customer unrelated to this order.  Is it possible to change the increment of the customer/user session ID?

Comment: Please change your  increment_last_id = 200000000 and test it again and see what happen.

Comment: Hey please let me know if this works for you. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically Table **eav_entity_store** storing store wise last increment id of order=5,invoice=6,creditmemo=7,shipment=8:

[image: Its list of entity type of magento from eav_entity_type table]

For Avoiding problem you can check all of increment id you can check it maximum increment id for each above type from admin sales >> orders,sales >> shipment,Sales >> invoice,sales >> credit memo
After getting all above info you need to add those increment id entry in eav_entity_store table store wise with corresponding entity type.